# Powershell equals dates is not equals

Tags: powershell

I'am trying to compare two dates, if they not equals, I write current date to txt file, but I always getting two dates different, even if I wrote new date to file right now.

```
$lastBackup=Get-Date (Get-Content -Path last_backup.txt)
"First date is: $lastBackup"
write-host

$lastModified = Get-Date ((Get-Item "My folder").LastWriteTime)
"Second date is: $lastModified"
write-host

if ($lastBackup -ne $lastModified)
{
    Set-Content -Path .\last_backup.txt -Value $lastModified -NoNewline
    "Dates are not equal"
    write-host
}
```

Output:

```
First date is: 03/13/2019 23:35:17

Second date is: 03/13/2019 23:35:17

Dates are not equal
```

$lastBackup and $lastModified are both DateTime objects.
What's wrong with this script?

Comment: Perhaps they are different in the milliseconds. Try `$lastBackup | fl * -Force` to see all of the values.

Comment: yup, you need to round the dates to either seconds or minutes. To see fraction do `$lastBackup.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **You cannot generally infer from the *string* representation of `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime)) instances whether they're exactly equal**.

  - The exact point in time stored in a `[datetime]` instance is generally not *fully* reflected in string representations.
- **Two `[datetime]` instances are only considered equal if their `.Ticks` property values are equal.**

  - The `.Ticks` property contains a `[long]` (`System.Int64`) value that expresses a point in time in terms of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight of January 1st of the year 1 A.D. in the Gregorian Calendar.

Therefore, if you want to **compare `[datetime]` instances** (just called *dates* in the discussion below) **at a *higher level of granularity***, additional work is needed:

**Use the appropriate `Get-Date` parameters to set  *all lower levels* of granularity to `0`**:

For instance, to **compare dates at the granularity of *seconds*** (to see if they fall into the same calendar second), **set the `-MilliSecond` component to `0`**:

```
$dtNow = Get-Date
$dtNowAgain = Get-Date

# This - predictably - returns $false, because the dates aren't exactly equal,
# given that the date values will at least differ by milliseconds, and
# possibly also by the seconds value.
$dtNow -eq $dtNowAgain

# You can abstract away the difference by setting the milliseconds
# component to 0 - this will *typically* return $true
# NOTE: If a new calendar second happened to start between setting $dtNow
#       and $dtNowAgain, this will return $false.
(Get-Date $dtNow -MilliSecond 0) -eq (Get-Date $dtNowAgain -MilliSecond 0)
```

To **compare at the level of *minutes*** (to see if they both fall into the same calendar minute), you must **set *both* `-Second` and `-MilliSecond` to `0`**:

```
# This will *typically* return $true.
# NOTE: If a new calendar minute happened to start between setting $dtNow
#       and $dtNowAgain, this will return $false.
(Get-Date $dtNow -Second 0 -MilliSecond 0) -eq (Get-Date $dtNowAgain -Second 0 -MilliSecond 0)
```

Note: **The advantage of the above approach over *string*-based comparison is that it ultimately still performs *numerical* comparisons**, so that not only *equality* testing works (`-eq`), but also *inequality* testing (`-lt` / `-le` / `-gt` / `-ge`), as well as *sorting*.

Answer (score 0):

Round dates to seconds/minutes/5th minutes, etc before comparsion. You can do either:

```
$date = Get-Date
$date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
$roundedDate = Get-Date -Year $date.Year -Month $date.Month -Day $date.Day -Hour $date.Hour -Minute $date.Minute -Second $date.Second -Millisecond 0
$roundedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

or see this link https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/rounding-a-date-in-powershell/

Comment: Couldn't you just do `$roundedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`